# How to populate another field with data which is being inserted

Tags: sql, sql-server, triggers

I have a table called 'DocumentHeaders'. There is a field which is populated on every insert called 'A'.

I want to populate another field called B with a link.
If the value inserted into column A is 'Giraffe', the structure of the link should be 'https://google.com/giraffe'.

Field 'C' has to be equal to 'new' for this trigger to be executed

This is what I have so far, and it doesn't seem to be working.
When I Insert a row, nothing happens. The row is inserted as normal without column B being populated

There is only ever one row inserted at a time to this database. I also can't include this as part of the insert query.

```
CREATE TRIGGER generate_new_link ON DocumentHeaders
AFTER INSERT
AS
BEGIN
    SET NOCOUNT ON;
    UPDATE DocumentHeaders SET B = CONCAT('https://google.com/', (SELECT A FROM INSERTED))
    FROM DocumentHeaders DH
    INNER JOIN INSERTED I ON DH.ID = I.ID
    WHERE I.C='new' or I.C='New'
    SET NOCOUNT OFF;
END
GO
```

Can anyone give me some guidance on where I might be going wrong?

Comment: *"it doesn't seem to be working"* What does this mean? Is it generating an error? Causing unexpected results? Undesired beahviour? CAusing a server crash? Something else..?

Comment: Your subquery, `(SELECT A FROM INSERTED)` is going to error if you ever `INSERT` 2 or more rows, as the subquery will return multiple rows.

Comment: @Larnu Thanks for your feedback. I have amended the post

Answer (score 0, accepted):

This was correct, but I needed to catch an update instead of an insert query.
So instead of After INSERT, It should have been After UPDATE.